# UPDATE table from another table, SELECT is good but UPDATE is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have to match two tables based on the rows `clients.client (VARCHAR)` and `clients_info.client (VARCHAR)` (like a text key).

`clients_info` has a one to many relationship to `clients` because the `clients` have various spellings that can match. There is no id field in the `clients_info` table and I'd like to populate that with the existing `clients.idx`.

When I run this query I get the results I want with a key I can associate with many groups of these spellings.

```sql
SELECT 
  clients_info.client, 
  clients.client AS c_client, 
  clients_info.idx 
FROM clients
INNER JOIN clients_info ON (clients_info.client = clients.client);
```

Output:

```
client           | c_client        |  idx
------------------------------------------
Real Corp        | Real Corp        | 180
Real Corp        | Real Corp        | 180
Real Corp        | Real Corp        | 180
Advantage People | Advantage People |  29
Advantage People | Advantage People |  29
Advantage People | Advantage People |  29
Others           | Others           |  392
Others           | Others           |  392
```

That's how the clients match up to the id they need. I've tried these but I'm not getting it right:

```sql
UPDATE clients 
INNER JOIN clients_info ON (clients.client = clients_info.client)
SET clients.client_info_id = cllients.idx;
```

```sql
UPDATE clients SET clients.client_info_id = (
    SELECT idx
    FROM clients_info
    WHERE clients_info.client = clients.client
    );
```

Comment: Typo: `cllients` has an extra `l`

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect results? Show the original table data and the desired result.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no id field in the clients_info table and I'd like to
> populate that with the existing clients.idx

The in both queries you are trying to update the clients table not the clients_info .

Below query will set the id on clients_info table equal to the idx on the client table for the matching rows.

```
UPDATE clients_info ci 
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client = ci.client
SET ci.id = c.idx;
```